# How can limits be applied to control the dimensions of a fixed position, centered DIV with variable content?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

The basic code is simple:

**CSS**

```
.pop {
  position: fixed ;
  top: 50%;     left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: yellow ; }
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="pop">some variable text.</div>
</body>
```

**BEHAVIOURS**

`div.pop` expands to fit its contents into a rectangle that, in a
viewport 915px wide, has a maximum width of 457.5px wide, and a
maximum height of 100%.

If the viewport is reduced, "margins" appear on either side of
`div.pop`, each taking up about a quarter of the viewport width.

Continuing to reduce the viewport width, the width of `div.pop` then
shrinks.  After it has shrunk to the width of its largest word the
proportion of the "margins" starts to shrink, until they disappear,
and the `div.pop` contents "overflow" the viewport.

**GOAL and PROBLEM**

I want to have a fixed position, centered DIV that does not exceed
e.g. 95% of the viewport or 30em, whichever is smallest, and that
ideally shrinks to fit content smaller than this, with a minimum width
of 10em.  I need to control the behaviours (above) to do this but have
been unable to find an explanation of them.

**APPROACHES**

I can't find a combination of `min-width`, `max-width`, and `width`
that achieves the goal.  `min-width` achieves the minimum width
requirement, but nothing seems to override the "margins", and maximum
width behaviours of `div.pop`.

Using `display:table-row;` and `display:table-cell;` seems to have no
effect, suggesting the maximum width and "margins" of `div.pop` are
not the result of anonymous cells.

From stripping out all code except that given here, it looks like the
"problem" comes from an intrinsic set of behaviours.  I have been
unable to find a definition of these or way they can be
controlled.

Including/omitting the Meyers reset css has no effect, so browser
presets don't seem to be involved.

FF Inspector displays the width of `div.pop` onscreen in the popup
associated with it; this width is also shown in the Box Model pane but
no computed width for it is given nor any rules relating to
that.

**QUESTION**

How are the dimensions of `div.pop` being calculated and the
behaviours being generated, and how can this be controlled to achieve
a goal like that described?

Comment: Have you tried using CSS functions like `minmax`, `min`, or `max`?

Comment: Thanks @AlphaHowl, I looked at those, and `clamp`, but need the 
solution to work on older, legacy devices :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using `max-width` and setting a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries):

```
.pop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: yellow ;
  width: 30em;
  min-width: 10em;
  }
@media (max-width: 30em) {
  .pop {
    max-width: 95%;
  }
}
```

If you need something more advanced, try using `calc` ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc())).

Comment: Thanks @user3236756 and @Dharman  Your answer demonstrates part of the 
problem: `min-width` doesn't shrink to content when `width` specified 
has a larger value.  As far as I understand `calc`, it generates a 
value for a CSS property but doesn't alter that property in any other 
way.